# Изменение темы устройства windows phone (цвет элементов) программно

Tags: c#

Есть множество примеров того как определить тему устройства windows phone7 для того что бы менять цвета выполняемой программы. У меня же возник вопрос как изменить тему устройства windows phone при выполнение моего приложения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вряд ли майкрософт даст такой апи (представьте себе пользователя, у которого тема меняется сама по себе), да и зачем вообще?

Comment: А все таки если кто знает скажите пожалуйста можно или нет? очень надо ...